# How to disable CLI graphics, colors, borders?

Tags: python, click, typer

I wonder whether it is possible to turn off / disable all those colors, borders etc. that Typer prints by default. I can't find any option for that. But on Typer docs website, there are images showing CLI without that stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Typer allows you to use Rich, so in theory you should be able to set a [Rich theme](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/style.html#style-themes) to the colors (or no colors) you want.

#### Edit:

I did some testing, and it seems installing `Typer` without the optional dependencies (`Rich` being one of them), is the most effective way to get a CLI without the colors and borders.

To install Typer without optional dependencies, run:

`pip install typer`
instead of

`pip install typer[all]`
as suggested in the docs.

Running the example from the Typer website yielded the following:

### Only Typer installed (no optional dependencies)

```
$: python typer_nocolor.py 

Usage: typer_nocolor.py [OPTIONS] NAME
Try 'typer_nocolor.py --help' for help.

Error: Missing argument 'NAME'.
```

*(codeblock for accessibility)*

[image: typer no colors or borders]

No borders or colors (other than what you might have your terminal configured to show)

### Typer with Rich installed alongside:

[image: typer with rich installed]

Comment: I looked at it at it seems that Typer is using its own theme in rich Console() object. But I don’t know, how to set it to “text-only” or at least get rid of the borders.

Comment: I see that Rich is an optional dependency of Typer, Have you tried installing just Typer without the optional deps? I don't have sufficient experience with Typer so I don't know if the borders come from Rich or not (although I suspect they do).

Comment: Answer updated to include example of my suggestion in comment above.

Comment: Thank you. I would say that it would depends on the optional dependencies.

Comment: Is it _really_ not possible to switch these colors off in a way other than by not installing `Rich`? That's very surprising.

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer especially when they go for something that is quite different than the norm... I was just trying to turn off the borders and stuff today too

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
sys.modules['rich'] = None

import typer
...
```

This causes `import rich` to throw a `ModuleNotFoundError` exception in all modules, even if it's installed. Set `sys.modules` before you `import typer` or `import` any other modules that might `import rich`

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules['rich'] = None
>>> 
>>> import rich
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: import of rich halted; None in sys.modules
>>>
```

When typer tries to `import rich` it catches the exception and continues as if rich wasn't installed.

Here's the code from https://github.com/tiangolo/typer/blob/master/typer/core.py

```
try:
    import rich

    from . import rich_utils

except ImportError:  # pragma: nocover
    rich = None  # type: ignore
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `pretty_exceptions_enable=False` when you're defining the typer variable.

```py
app = typer.Typer(pretty_exceptions_enable=False)
```

you can find it here https://typer.tiangolo.com/tutorial/exceptions/#disable-pretty-exceptions